# proof the regularity of the measure in the Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

real and complex analysis , walter rudin , page 48 , theorem 2.17 , the (b)
how did he prove the inner regularity of the measure , please explain [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of reasoning is always omitted in it, so we have to always fill the gap of proofs of Rudin.

For the proof, you have to consider 2 cases.

Given a set $E$ measurable and $\epsilon>0$,

1. $\mu(E)<\infty$

In this case, by (a), we can choose a closed set $F$ with the measure $\mu(E-F)<\epsilon$. 
Then since $F$ is $\sigma$-compact and of finite measure, we can choose a compact set $C\subset F$ such that $\mu(F-C)<\epsilon$

(Or, you may consider a increasing sequence of compact sets converging to $F$. Note that finite union of compact sets is compact.)

Thus we have $\mu(E-C)<2\epsilon$ or $\mu(E)<\mu(C)+2\epsilon$. I think the finiteness condition should be used here.

2. $\mu(E)=\infty$

I'd like to leave this case as an exercise since it is almost the same proof as above, except that we cannot use $\epsilon$ argument. Instead, you can choose a closed subset $F$ of infinite measure and a increasing sequence of compact sets in $F$ whose measure converges to $\infty$, which anyway implies that $\mu(E)=sup\{\mu(C): C \text{ is compact and }C\subset E \}$

Comment: you meant we should prove that the measure of the measurable can be given by the supremum therefore we found the compact set $C$

Comment: Right. That is the definition of inner regularity in the book.