# Proof of Theorem 2.17 (a) From Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> $\bf 2.17\ $ **Theorem** $\ $ *Suppose $X$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. If $\frak M$ and $\mu$ are as described in the statement of Theorem $\it 2.14$, then $\frak M$ and $\mu$ have the following properties:*
>
> $(a)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F$ and an open set $V$ such that $F\subset E\subset V$ and $\mu(V-F)<\epsilon$.
>   $(b)\ \ $ $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$.
>   $(c)\ \ $ If $E\in\frak M$, there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an $F_\sigma$, $B$ is a $G_b$, $A\subset E\subset B$, and $\mu(B-A)=0.$
>
> $\rm P\scriptstyle{\rm ROOF}$
>
> $\quad$ Let $X=\cup_{n} K_n$, where each $K_n$ is compact. If $E \in \frak M$ and $\epsilon>0$, then $\mu(K_n \cap E) < \infty$, and there are open sets $V_n$ such that $K_n \cap E \subset V_n$. Hence $$\mu(V_n-(K_n \cap E))< \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$$ If $V= \cup V_n$, then $$\mu(V-E)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
>   Apply this to $E^{c}$ in place of E: there is an open set $E^{c} \subset W$ such that $\mu(W-E^{c}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. If $F=W^{c}$, and $F\subset E$, and $E-F =W-E^{c}$. Now (a) follows.

I understood the proof given in the book but I'm not sure why we couldn't just assume such an open set $V$ must exist: by Theorem 2.14 (Riesz Representation Theorem), $\mu$ is outer regular itself, so there exits an open set $V$ such that $\mu(V-E)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Why do we have to go through the construction of $V$ in the proof? Is it because we are worried that $\mu(E)$ might be infinity.

Note: this is not question from Baby's Rudin.

Comment: Hi, this is not a question from Baby's Rudin. So it was irrelevant.

Comment: Oi... I misread the title.  Give me a minute...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838898/theorem-2-17-from-rca-rudin

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=rudin+2.17+complex+is%3Aquestion

Comment: The point is that nearly every exercise from each of Rudin's books has almost certainly been asked-and-answered here before.  Your first step should be to search the site; then, if you can't find your answer, make some reference to older questions, and explain how they don't answer your question.

Comment: I'm checking whether the search that Xander linked contains a duplicate of this question. But either way: Yes, the issue is with sets of infinite measure, $\mu(E) = \inf \:\{\mu(V) : E \subset V, V\text{ open}\}$ doesn't give the desired $V$ when $\mu(E) = +\infty$.

Comment: This answer might be more to the point: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2380802/468350

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now. I'll do more research when I ask rudin's questions next time. Thank you for your time.